# Iterating through find_all with decompose() has no effect

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I want to remove long runs (50+) of either `&nbsp;&nbsp;` or `&nbsp; &nbsp;` (trailing space clipped here?), but `decompose()` has no effect in an iteration through `.find_all`. For the BeautifulSoup regex, `&nbsp;` has been converted into unicode.

Printing in the iteration shows that something *was* found ("..snipped.." means I shortened overly long lines):

```
compileMe = ('(' + u'\xa0' + ' *){50,}') 
for i in (soup.find_all('p', string=re.compile(compileMe))):
    print(i)  # ==> " <p>        ..snipped..       </p>"
    print(i.text.strip())  # ==> "      ..snipped..       "
    print(i.text.strip)  # ==> "<built-in method strip of str object at 0x110184c30>"
    i.decompose()  # ==> no effect on output
    i.p.decompose()  # ==> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'
```

Output html still contains the  :

```
 <p>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;..snipped..;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>
  </strong>
 </p>
```

P.S.: There is no "decompose()" tag, would creating one be warranted?

Comment: Did you mean `print(i.text.strip())`?

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. `print(i.text.strip())` returns the whitespace lines. OP edited to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Answering for anyone running into the same trap:

The decomposing was blocked by a tag (already emptied with a previous decompose) inside the `<p>` to decompose. Removing it first (`find_all('thisEmptyTag', text='')`) fixed the issue.

EDIT: It is important to use `text` and not `string`, because `text` includes all the child strings. To whomever it may help...